# Is there a way to easily add image swap/rollover to images on a Basic Page?

Tags: media

I would like to do some simple image rollovers on a Basic Page, without having to write a bunch of individual CSS cases for each specific image. (Ie. - swap Img1 for Img2 on mouseover.) Is there an easy way, or a useful module that anyone knows of?  I didn't find anything on drupal.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Rollover Filter](https://drupal.org/project/rollover_filter) module. This is the only module for rollover effect AFAIK.

> This module provides a simple method to enable content editors to use
>   image rollover states. It makes no checks against the referenced image
>   types, it simply converts [rollover] wrappers into actual rollover
>   images. It does use a Javascript based approach, and causes no harm to
>   images in an environment where there is no Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, Bala! That's the kind of thing I was looking for!  I don't know why it didn't turn up when I searched terms like "rollover" on drupal.org!

Comment: @eljefejb always search globally. use google :)